# Statement true for all prime numbers -- can this be done by Math Induction?

Tags: induction

Let's say that you want to prove a statement is true for all prime numbers.  Can this be done by Math Induction?

Comment: Sure. First prove that if it is true for some prime, it is true then for the next one. Then prove it is true for the first prime and you're done.

Comment: So you can use Math Induction to prove a statement is true for all prime numbers because they are all positive, right?

Comment: Try it for Cauchy's theorem. If a prime $p$ divides the order of $G$, then $G$ has an element of order $p$. This is true for all primes.

Comment: It can be done with Cauchy's Theorem, but mathematically speaking, it can be done by only using Math Induction, correct?

Comment: Cauchy's Theorem can be proved by strong induction, yes, but it is not so straightforward.

Comment: @Zapper Nona He means *proving* Cauchy's theorem by induction.

Comment: Ok I am a little confused now, sorry.  I don't want to relate Cauchy's Theorem or anything - just simple Math Induction.  Let's say we have a statement, and want to prove if it is true for all prime numbers - could this be, 1. solved by Math Induction because the statement regards all positive numbers, 2. Can't solve because it doesn't relate all positive integers, 3. because numbers aren't evenly spaced, or 4. you can use math induction if you ignore 2.

Comment: Well, think about FLT. Can it be done?

Comment: So would it be 1, 2, 3, or 4? (look at my comment above).  Thanks!

Comment: Fermat concerns all positive integers and all prime numbers.

Comment: So would the answer be 1, 2, 3, or 4? (for math induction only, not FLT)

Comment: No, none of 1,2,3,4 for FLT by induction.

Comment: Wait actually but I am asking for Math Induction only, not FLT - i know it is not known if it can be solved by Math Induction, but Math Induction only, not FLT, would it be 1, 2, 3, or 4?

Comment: I don't understand. Your question asks for a "statement" (so FLT here), to be proved by induction over primes. So this is unknown for "this statement".

Comment: I do not want to use the FLT here.  For any particular statement, I want to know if it could be proved by Math Induction only - for all prime numbers (i know it is not known, but out of my options 1,2,3,4 above), which one would work best?

Comment: "For any particular statement" you cannot exclude a negative result, like for FLT. You want to exclude FLT - good. But then you have to exclude many other statements, so this doesn't make sense.

Comment: Alright I understand.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: You need to be precise about what you mean by "mathematical induction." It's perfectly correct to prove "For all primes $p$, property $A(p)$ holds" by showing (1) $A(2)$ holds, and (2) For any prime $p$, if $A(p)$ holds, then $A(p*)$ holds [where $p*$ denotes the next prime after $p$]. However unlike more basic induction arguments, you don't have a simple fixed formula for $p*$ in terms of $p$. But the logic is fine, if that's your question.

Comment: That was my question!  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say that you want to prove a statement is true for all prime numbers.
Such as Fermat's Last Theorem:

$$ X^p+Y^p=Z^p$$

has no non-trivial integer solutions for all primes $p>2$.

Can this be done by Math Induction?

This is not known.